# Does flutter kicks effects sexual health?

Tags: abdominals, sex

I am 31 year old, Male and unmarried with weight 83 kgs of height 5ft 8inch.
I addicted to abdominal workouts like [Flutter kicks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHxbqt9ApdM).
Does this abdominal workouts effect sexual health?

I feel [Flutter kicks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHxbqt9ApdM) cause **friction between thighs** which may cause heat which ultimately kills
sperm counts.

Comment: Looks like the same kind of friction you'd get by walking or running, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fine to do flutter kicks. Any workout, really.

While there is truth to the idea that heat kills sperm cells, it is more centered around extended use of saunas, hot tubs and similar high heat environments. You are not going to create that kind of heat doing workouts.

And in addition, once you remove the heat source sperm counts go back to normal (For whatever is normal for you) very quickly.